# How to fix RequestError for python Elasticsearch bulk?

Tags: json, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm trying to read data from a website and save to Elasticsearch. But I got the following error. I think its because of my doc which isn't correct. I followed the bulk elastic documentation. Still I'm struggling how to solve this. Can someone help me?

My error:

> RequestError: RequestError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 'Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: type is missing;')

My code is:

```
import os
import requests
import time
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
import json
es = Elasticsearch('http://ip:port',timeout=600)
while (True):
 df = requests.get("https://my url").json()  

 del df["positions"][1]
 print(df)
 def gendata(df):
    for word in df:
        yield {
        "_index": "chapter",
        "doc": {"info": {
                          "satnam":{"type":"text"},
                          "satid":{"type":"integer"},
                          "transactionscount":{"type":"integer"}},
                "positions": {"satlatitude":{"type":"float"},
                          "satlongitude":{"type":"float"},
                          "sataltitude":{"type":"float"},
                          "azimuth":{"type":"float"},
                          "elevation":{"type":"float"},
                          "ra": {"type":"float"},
                           "dec": {"type":"float"},
                           "timestamp":{"type":"datetime"} }}
    }
 bulk(es,gendata(df))
 time.sleep(10)`
```

> My Json file from website is:

{"info":{"satname":"SPACE STATION","satid":00000,"transactionscount":0},
"positions":{"satlatitude":-50.00807313,"satlongitude":-37.47024176,"sataltitude":435.04,"azimuth":178.02,"elevation":-47.22,"ra":132.83647708,"dec":-72.05784906,"timestamp":1589984178}

Comment: Whatever dictionary you are returning from `yield` statement, have you tried indexing that separately as a single document to your elastic ? Does that work ?

Comment: No that way also not working, gave error SerializationError:

Comment: It isn't possible to send streaming data with es bulk?

Comment: If you are getting an error while trying the single doc , then there should be  something wrong with the doc(json payload) you are trying to pass to Elastic.

Comment: bulk should be possible.just for debugging the issue i asked if its working for single-doc

Comment: So, do you think that the way I've written in  "doc" isn't match with my json data? Actually I need to find where the my error is.I tried but still didn't get. Can you pls?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat, I cheked my json format in doc with "JSONLint", it's in correct format. I don't undesrtand where the my error is

Comment: i just tried with your document for single object - it is working . I would suggest you to keep your same code , but add this line after the line you have created the Elasticsearch instance   :  `es.indices.create(index='chapter', ignore=400)`

Comment: Sorry it's not working, giving RequestError: RequestError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 'Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: type is missing;').  I'm wondering how others use this bulk insertions.

Answer (score 0):

Main thing: You are doing a `bulk()` for your mappings . You are supposed to do it for your document objects.

So this is how your code should get refactored:

- Create the index 'chapter'.
- Create the mappings for 'chapter' index however you expect it to have the documents.
- Then start indexing documents to the index.

And another thing: 
you don't need to declare mappings in json style - better approach to use `elasticsearch-dsl` => https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

So you would be defining a class like so (please see details in above reference):

```
class Chapter(Document):
    satnam=Text()
    satid=Integer()
    transactionscount=Integer()
    .
    .
    .


    class Index:
        name = 'chapter'
```

This class is mainly for giving mapping-details/index-name/analyzers etc.

Once you call `Chapter.init()` - the index 'chapter' will be created.

And then comes your code for bulk indexing the documents into the 'chapter' index which you just created using init().

Comment: 'positions' you can use `Nested()` - just check that documentation if nested is what will satisfy your requirement for 'positions'

Comment: I'll try and pls, this class should be outside my while loop?

Comment: yes . please go through OOPS concepts in python if you dont have idea about python classes-objects

Comment: To streaming data I did some other way ( appreciate your thoughts though) , it worked. But little struggling to convert numbers data type to gep-point. My question posted as "Why does geospatial data not convert from numbers to geo-point with Python client with Elastisearch?". Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your bulk insert elastic query format is wrong
the expected query syntax would be

```
{"index": {"_index": "chapter"}}
{"info": {
                          "satnam":{"type":"text"},
                          "satid":{"type":"integer"},
                          "transactionscount":{"type":"integer"}},
                "positions": {"satlatitude":{"type":"float"},
                          "satlongitude":{"type":"float"},
                          "sataltitude":{"type":"float"},
                          "azimuth":{"type":"float"},
                          "elevation":{"type":"float"},
                          "ra": {"type":"float"},
                           "dec": {"type":"float"},
                           "timestamp":{"type":"datetime"} }}
```

reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html